# random 15px margins?

Tags: html, css, margin

I am getting random 15px top and bottom margins and I have no idea where they are coming from.

This is not happening in IE, only FF and Chrome.

In the following sample, the spacing above and below each "Here is content" paragraph was unexpected.

```css
#pageContent {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#contentHead {
    height: 33px;
    width: 882px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 34px;
    padding-left: 48px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#contentBody{
    background-color: #d4d3d1;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #8b8b8b;
}

#contentNoSidebar{
    background-color: #000;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="pageContent">
  <div id="contentHead">Sample Page</div>
  <div id="contentBody">
    <div id="contentNoSidebar">
      <p>Here is content</p>
      ...
      <p>Here is content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which elements are the unexpected margins appearing upon?

Comment: i can't see any margins in chrome browser?!?

Comment: Your provided test page looks the same in IE and Firefox. The only margins I can see are the default ones belonging to the `<p>` tags, which you can get rid of with `p { margin: 0 }`. Please revise your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're talking about the margins surrounding each `<p>` tag, that is inherent from the user agent style sheet.
By default paragraph tags have a surrounding margin. If you do something like:

```
p { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

you should be able to get rid of the margin/padding.

Answer (score 1):

Paragraphs default to 1em vertical margin (top and bottom, but they can overlap). I guess you're talking about the div having a bottom margin - but it doesn't, that's the top margin of the `p` below it.

Comment: I think answers should be accepted based on usefulness, not entirely speed - but I'll admit, our answers were pretty similar. :)

Answer (score 1):

Now you added a test image, I know what you mean.

Use this CSS to fix the issue:

```
p { margin: 0; padding: 16px 0 }
```

In short, provide the same spacing between paragraphs using `padding` instead of `margin`.

Comment: That's not a good idea. In the first place, that will be ugly if you have a non-default font size. Also, this will add 32px of space between two consecutive paragraphs.

Comment: Ms2ger: Yup, I clearly didn't think my answer out very well. I should have just posted my original comment as my answer, that was exactly what the asker wanted, and I wrote it sooner than the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

Delete the -`-moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;` command on your content body css and use 
 margin:0 px; padding based on your content.It will work, this is the reason for the reputation. Use firebug in your mozila browser we can easily find the bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions seems resolved already, but you might want to start using a CSS reset to override user agent stylesheet stuff for everything. Makes styling your web pages so they look the same on most browsers easier.

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, naturally. :) User agent styles can be a big mischief so, defining stuff yourself should in most cases be better.